# Modal component failed in WebExtensions content script

Tags: getuikit

when using uikit v3.0.0-beta.35 modal component in WebExtentions content script did not show and I get this error `TypeError: 'requestAnimationFrame' called on an object that does not implement interface Window.`

here is my code

```
import UIkit from 'uikit';
//....
UIkit.modal.confirm('UIkit confirm!').then(function() {
  console.log('Confirmed.')
}, function () {
  console.log('Rejected.')
});
```